# Python choose random choice from variables linked together

Tags: python, random

I am learning python, and want to know how could I chose a random set from a list like this:

```
List1:
animal = 'dog'
legs = '4'
food = 'bones'
place = 'outside'

List2:
animal = 'chicken'
legs = '2'
food = 'corn'
place 'chicken coop'
```

I want each time my script runs to choose a different list, something like: 
python(random.choice(list))

EDIT: Wow this community is harsh! I want to choose a random list to be used later in the script. I have 10 lists, and I want one to work it, I don't know if they are called lists, dictionaries, arrays or idk. When I do random, i want one of them to be selected so I can use those variables inside of it.

Comment: 1) those arent lists 2) http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  What have you researched about random in python, what code did you write to solve your issue, and what problem did you come across that you could not overcome?

Comment: Choosing a random element from a list is well documented on line.  How did your research not find *anything* you could use?

Comment: I am not trying to choose 1 ELEMENT randomly, i am trying to choose a random LIST to use !

Comment: Replace 'LIST" with "FARM1" and "FARM2", it will make more sense then I guess. Again, I am trying to select a random FARM so i can work with the variables inside of it later on in the script.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, [lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) are assigned using [ ]

UPDATE to your question:

Use nested lists:

```
Farms = [["dog","4","bones","outside"],["chicken","2","corn","chicken coop"]]
```

The [module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm) [random](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/random/how-to-use-the-random-module-in-python) can then be used to make a random selection from a list:

```
print(random.choice(Farms))
>>>["dog","4","bones","outside"]
```

Please use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) to attempt your own code before coming to this site.

Good luck with Python!

Comment: @AlexGap Consider showing us the desired output, what do you mean by "select". Do you mean print the list, or store it as a variable? More context required...